# Flex CrossDomain.xml Error - Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048

Tags: apache-flex, crossdomain.xml

I am struggling with getting a Flex SWF (which is embedded in JSP) to access remote data (from another domain).

I have a crossdomain.xml (which is embedded in my SWF). Its content is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />  
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

In my main.xml I load the crossdomain.xml file using:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://www.mysite.com:8380/CSS/ReviewItemsServer/crossdomain.xml");
```

When I access the JSP webpage via the browser, the embedded SWF tries to do a Java remoting call and I get the following error:

```
Error string = Send failed
Error code = Client.Error.MessageSend
Error details = Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048: 
Security sandbox violation: http://www.mysite.com/CSS/ReviewItemsServer/ReviewItemsMain.swf 
cannot load data from http://www.mysite.com:8380/CSS/ReviewItemsServer/messagebroker/amf. url:
```

I am pretty sure that the crossdomain.xml file actually get loaded by the SWF as I have created a simple URLLoader to load the xml file and check that there is no error. So I dont think that is an issue...

When I run the SWF in debug mode...I also see the following error message:

```
Error: [strict] Ignoring policy file at http://www.mysite.com:8380/CSS/ReviewItemsServer/crossdomain.xml due to missing Content-Type.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files to fix this problem.
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated....

Mark

Answer (score 3):

You need a master policy file at http://www.mysite.com:8380/crossdomain.xml with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<cross-domain-policy> 
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

That will permit crossdomain policy files in subdirectories to be used.

Comment: Thanks James, what is the master policy file called? and how does the SWF load it?

Comment: The master policy file in your case is: http://www.mysite.com:8380/crossdomain.xml  It will be loaded automatically by Flash Player.